# How to Make my Chrome Homepage an Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is an interesting one. We want to use the extension "Kiosk" for our computers to lock down the browser to only allow our website to play but we need it to auto load to that.

We have another security layer that will lock down the computer on boot up, which we can assign a application to run (chrome in this case). All we need to do is make sure that when Chrome is loaded it boots directly into the "Kiosk" Extension.

We have the extension ID, but we cannot get chrome to assign the extension as the home page.

Has anyone done something like this in the past?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"chrome_url_overrides"` inside your `manifest.json` to override 
Chromes new tab and some other Chrome pages.

For example:

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "new-tab.html"
}
```

You can also redirect to any other site within your HTML file.
You can read about it more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

Edit:

Like I said in the comments you can also create a `.bat` file to run on startup that is going to open your kiosk app.

The code inside your `.bat` file can look like this:

```
start chrome.exe --app-id=afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban
```

You can also add more parameters if you require any more settings when starting `chrome.exe`.

Comment: I have seen this option before but the problem that I am having is using the extension id as a URL. The ID is afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban is that helps at all.

Comment: @C.Hebert What exactly is the problem? Where do you require to use it where you cant?

Comment: We need to launch Chrome directly into the "Kiosk" Extension. So I understand the url_override but I do not understand how to call the extension. We have used the override to call other pages but the problem is the "Kiosk" extension is the only way we have found to completely disable zoom without deterring other touch functions.

Comment: @C.Hebert Just to clarify, you are using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban?hl=en) Kiosk extension? Or at least something like that? Then I suggest making a bat file that can also run on startup which is gonna start that chrome app, I can also give you the example of that bat file.